# Location Permissions on Android

Tags: android, geolocation, location, android-permissions, locationmanager

I know there are two different types of location permissions

- `ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION`
- `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

I know that for using the location from Android M, we require runtime permission form the User. Now the issue is that both `ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` falls under the same bucket and which implies that granting one runtime permission will grant the other one without asking the user.

So, now my doubt is that if I just ask `ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION` permission and still can have the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` then why should I need to request `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`? Can I just get a fine location with just `ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION` location permission?

Also, I am requesting a location fix with the below criteria

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setBearingAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_MEDIUM);
criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_MEDIUM);
riteria.setCostAllowed(false);
```

So how do the two different permissions affect the location fix I am getting with the above criteria?.

**EDIT 1:** Rephrasing the question. I know about the different providers like GPS, network, etc. and which permission they require. That's why my doubt is that if granting `ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION` can result in granting `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. Then can we have a situation during app lifecycle where we have only `ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION` granted? Also, how would the above criteria behave?

**EDIT 2:** Few other StackOverflow answers says that `ACCESS_COURSE_LOCATION` can be eliminated when `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` is granted. But if I just want a course location, I request permission and then I request location fix using the above criteria. So what should I expect a course location or a fine location? as granting course location is internally granting the fine location permission as well.

Comment: you don't need `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` if you' already defined `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` . Accuracy can vary between Only Network Provider and GPS Provider.. [Read This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775257/android-location-providers-gps-or-network-provider) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310742/if-i-have-access-fine-location-already-can-i-omit-access-coarse-location).

Comment: @ADM I already know about the providers and which permissions they require. That's why my doubt is that how can I have a situation where I can only grant `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION `?

Comment: [When should I use ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869610/when-should-i-use-access-coarse-location-permission)

Comment: @ADM Again this answer just says that `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` can be eliminated when you have `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission. But let's say I don't want fine location I just want course location so I request course location and then a location fix with the criteria mentioned in the question. So now the situation would be that I have fine permission as well so it is giving me a fine accurate location, not course location.