# How to distinguish "Never ask again" state and "Canceled" state for Android runtime permission?

Tags: android, android-permissions

User can cancel a permission request by hitting the "Back" button. And since Android 11, user can also clicking on the outside of the permission dialog to cancel. When a permission is canceled, the permission is not granted, and shouldShowPermissionRationale() will return false, which means app can call requestPermissions() again.

When user choose "Don't ask again", or deny twice for a permission in Android 11, shouldShowPermissionRationale() will also return false. But how can I distinguish "Don't ask again" from the "Canceled" state?

I need to distinguish these two states is because that if user canceled a permission before, I know that I still have the chance to prompt the system permission dialog to them. But if user choose not to ask for a permission again, I need to guide them to the app info page to grant the permission manually.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69530502/how-can-we-determine-if-we-can-request-location-permission-upgrade-in-android-12

Comment: @blackapps the problem is not exactly the same with mine. The link doesn't mention the case where user cancel the permission dialog.

Comment: @littledog Did you happen to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value of `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` before requesting permission. And check whether it has been modified after the permission request result callback. Is considered to be "Never ask again" state,  When the old value is true and new value is false.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a direct solution to this problem because there appears to be no way to get that.

However, I have realised that there is a method where Android will tell us if we need to show `RationaleDialog` to our user without any work from our end (before I was under impression we need to keep track of this ourselves).

Just call `activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission)` and it will take care of all back calls itself.