# How to check if a user was never requested for a permission in android?

Tags: android

I need to check if a user was already requested for a permission or not.

What I already know is this:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
```

- User was never requested: *denied*
- User was requested and did not allow: *denied*
- User was requested two times and did not allow: *denied*
- User was requested and did allow: *granted*

---

```
activity.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
```

- User was never requested: *false*
- User was requested and did not allow: *true*
- User was requested two times and did not allow: *false*
- User was requested and did allow: *false*

---

I need to differentiate between "User was never requested" and "User was requested two times and did not allow".

I can't save the count of my requests, because I'm building a plugin. So I can't be sure if the user was already asked by the app.

Is there a way to check if the user was never asked for the permission?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69530502/how-can-we-determine-if-we-can-request-location-permission-upgrade-in-android-12